# Order of psalms in Pesukei deZimra

Tags: minhag, shabbat, chagim-holidays, pesukei-dezimra

Both Ashkenazim and Sephardim [add various psalms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pesukei_dezimra#Shabbat/Yom_Tov_additions) to *Pesukei deZimra* on Shabbath and on holidays. [Rambam](https://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/1508041/jewish/Order-of-Prayers-Order-of-Prayer-for-the-Entire-Year.htm) mentions Psalm [92](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt2692.htm), [136](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26d6.htm), [121](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26c1.htm)–[124](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt26c4.htm), but are there any sources why these particular psalms were selected and why in their particular order?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Levush* ([OC 281:1](https://books.google.com/books?id=4eFDAAAAYAAJ&pg=PP262&dq=%D7%90%D7%95+%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94+%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA+%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95+%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi6gKbQ_ezZAhWp34MKHZ3zDkYQ6AEIKDAA#v=onepage&q=%D7%90%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%9E%D7%A2%D7%A9%D7%94%20%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA%20%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%9C%D7%95%20%D7%91%D7%A9%D7%91%D7%AA&f=false)) writes the reason they are read is either because they speak about Creation, which was completed on *Shabbos*, or they speak about the giving of the Torah, which was given on *Shabbos*. He also notes that they are grouped by these subjects, rather than by the order in which they were written.

He then goes on to explain the precise order:

1. Psalms 19: It is the first that deals with Creation.
2. Psalms 34: It is the first to speak about *Shabbos*.
3. Psalms 90: Also speaks about *Shabbos*.
4. Psalms 91: To save us from [evil spirits that roam on Friday night](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/89083/9643).
5. Psalms 135: Speaks of the giving of the *Torah*.
6. Psalms 136 ([The "Great Halel"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psalm_136)): It contains 26 mentions of the phrase "For His kindness is everlasting", corresponding to the 26 generations from Creation till the Giving of the *Torah*.
7. Psalms 36: It is only after The Great Halel that the righteous will praise
   *Hashem* for his great kindness. Psalms 92: Further praise to *Hashem*.
8. Psalms 93: Signifies the completion of the Creation, when *Hashem* sat on his Throne of Glory.